# Ruby AWS SDK Loop Through Bucket Objects to Create url

Tags: ruby, aws-sdk

I'm new to AWS and I'm trying to loop through my bucket objects to generate urls to read the objects.  I found the following reference in the AWS documentation:

```
bucket.objects.myobject.url_for(:read)
```

I have the following method which contains a loop that can at least print the key for each object BUT I'm struggling to get the url_for to work.  Any ideas?

```
  def aws_s3_url
    s3_client = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: ENV['AWS_REGION'])
    bucket = s3_client.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET'])

    bucket.objects.each do |name|
      puts name.key
    end
  end
```

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the specific use-case you have, but you don't need the URL to read the objects in the bucket since the AWS SDK maps the files in the bucket to instances of [Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Object.html).

To read the contents of the file, try this:

```
@s3_client = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: ENV['AWS_REGION'])

def file_content(key)
  bucket = @s3_client.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET'])

  obj = @s3_client.get_object(bucket: bucket, key: key)
  obj.body.read
end

def get_all_files
  bucket = @s3_client.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET'])

  bucket.objects.each do |o|
    puts file_content(o.key)
  end
end
```

To return the public URL for the object, you can try:

[Aws::S3::Object.public_url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#public_url-instance_method):

```
def get_url(key)
  bucket = @s3_client.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET'])

  obj = @s3_client.get_object(bucket: bucket, key: key)
  obj.public_url
end
```